# Unit testing for spark-bigquery-connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-bigquery, spark-streaming, spark-bigquery-connector

I am trying to write unit test case for my spark bigquery implementation.
Say, If I want to test this below piece of code:

```
val wordsDF = (spark.read.format("bigquery")
              .option("table","bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare")
              .load()
              .cache())
```

And do some assertion on wordsDF

I am trying to think on the lines of:

- Embedded kafka for kafka
- Embedded cassandra for cassandra

Do we have any such library or alternative that can be used to write spark bigquery unit test

Comment: Not sure about what u trying to test, but unit test would be with static values wordsDF (not from remote data which is already tested by spark), im using "com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base"

Comment: Actually i want to mock bigquery

Comment: Maybe try this, this look complete https://github.com/samelamin/spark-bigquery/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/samelamin/spark/bigquery/BigQueryClientSpecs.scala